# Puppet semodule: how to add a .te file?

Tags: puppet, selinux

I'm using https://forge.puppetlabs.com/spiette/selinux

In site.pp for a node where I want the module installed I have:

```
selinux::module { "varnishlnkfile":
  ensure => "present",
  source => "puppet:///modules/selinux/modules",
}
```

and I'm getting:

```
err: /File[/varnishlnkfile.te]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment development source(s) puppet:///modules/selinux/varnishlnkfile.te at /etc/puppet/modules/selinux/manifests/module.pp:52
```

I found this GitHub issue https://github.com/spiette/puppet-selinux/issues/5 but following it does not change anything.

The .te file is in:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/selinux/varnishlnkfile.te
```

Earlier it was in:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/selinux/modules/varnishlnkfile.te
```

and the error message was the same.

Comment: Can you show where you've put the varnishlnkfile.te file on the filesystem, and in relation to the selinux module?

Comment: Edited with paths. The puppet:/// links are in relation to modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URL for the agent to retrieve `/etc/puppet/modules/selinux/varnishlnkfile.te` is

```
puppet:///modules/selinux/varnishlnkfile.te
```

For `/etc/puppet/modules/selinux/modules/varnishlnkfile.te` it's

```
puppet:///modules/selinux/modules/varnishlnkfile.te
```

The error does not seem to relate to the manifest you pasted. If this doesn't help, please clean up your question with one consistent set of information.